# How long php cron job are handled which is set to repeat in short time period?

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

I have a php cron job which needs to run every minute. The job takes five to seven minutes to finish. How are such type of crons managed?
Does it interrupts the previous job and start running as a fresh job or does it starts the new job parallel to previous job?
Should i break the big job into smaller ones and add each as a different cron job?

Comment: please add your cronjob (commands etc)

Comment: such a situation u can use  parallel / multithreading in PHP

Comment: @Lohardt Actually cronjob is long php script.

Comment: yes, but how is it executed i.e what command are you using? 
# * * * * *  command to execute

Comment: Usually the script is not interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like the following in the script:

1. Check for the existence of a lock file.  If one is found, exit the
   script
2. Create a lock file
3. Do some processing
4. Release the lock file.
5. Exit

You may need to also add some additional logic in step 1 if the script aborts for some unknown reason and doesn't delete the lock file.  For example, the lock file could contain the PID of the process that created it.  Then the next run of the job could check for the existence of the lock file as well as the existence of the PID.  If either are missing, delete the lock file and continue on as if it never existed.

Comment: I have used that approach with success. But that's not exactly what OP is asking. You are solving the problem he is likely to get afterwords :)